# How to get storm streaming failure processed tuples

Tags: stream, streaming, apache-storm

I know that storm provide a functionality that you could ack every tuple you processed, but if I want to evaluate how the storm performed and get the performance information about the topology or bolts(e.g. how many failure to ack and how many latency of each bolt etc.)

Where can I find these data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storm has an web interface available exactly for that, called *Storm UI*, which can be started with the

```
./storm ui
```

command, and is accessible by default on port 8080.

Lots of useful information and statistics is available there, however, you must know how to interpret it, since there's not much documentation on Storm yet, except for the mailing list and the wiki pages.

Comment: Sorry, which folder should I look into, I just use the storm maven import the storm functionality, but never see any ui things

Comment: Look inside your STORM_DIR/bin